# Comparing four UITextFields' text property

Tags: swift3, uitextfield, string-comparison

I would like to compare four UITextFields' text property to make sure they are not the same. Ie:

```
tbx1.text = "hello"
tbx2.text = "goodbye"
tbx3.text = "goodnight"
tbx4.text = "hello"
```

should return a false but

```
tbx1.text = "hello"
tbx2.text = "goodbye"
tbx3.text = "goodnight"
tbx4.text = "good morning"
```

should return a true.

I know I could use a long and complicated if statement but I'm hoping there is a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to add all Strings to a Set and check the count of the set. If it is 4, all textfields had a different value, if it is less than 4, you had duplicates.

You can even generalise it to work with a different number of text fields as well. You just add all textfields' text property to an array, create a `Set` from the array then compare the number of elements in the two collections.

```
let textFieldValues = [tbx1.text!, tbx2.text!, tbx3.text!, tbx4.text!]
let textFieldSet = Set(textFieldValues)
if textFieldSet.count == textFieldValues.count {
    print("No duplicates")
} else {
    print("Some duplicates")
}
```

Comment: thank you but that gives me an error: Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred'

Comment: let textFieldValues = [tbx1.text!, tbx2.text!, tbx3.text!, tbx4.text!] solved your answer.. please updated and I will accept your answer